# is .then supported by Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, deferred

I have read that IE does not support promises, however I have legacy code with .then which seems to run fine on IE.

How can this be as my understanding is .then = promises?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Promise.prototype.then() method returns a Promise. This method still doesn't support IE browser. You could check the [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

To use the Promise and Then method in IE 11 browser, you can use 3rd party promise library (like Bluebird) or [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/) transpiler to convert the ES6 code to ES5 code. Please refer the following sample code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js"></script> 

<script>
    (function (global, factory) {
        if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
            define([], factory);
        } else if (typeof exports !== "undefined") {
            factory();
        } else {
            var mod = {
                exports: {}
            };
            factory();
            global.repl = mod.exports;
        }
    })(typeof globalThis !== "undefined" ? globalThis : typeof self !== "undefined" ? self : this, function () {
        "use strict";

        var myFirstPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            // We call resolve(...) when what we were doing asynchronously was successful, and reject(...) when it failed.
            // In this example, we use setTimeout(...) to simulate async code. 
            // In reality, you will probably be using something like XHR or an HTML5 API.
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve("Success!"); // Yay! Everything went well!
            }, 250);
        });
        myFirstPromise.then(function (successMessage) {
            // successMessage is whatever we passed in the resolve(...) function above.
            // It doesn't have to be a string, but if it is only a succeed message, it probably will be.
            console.log("Yay! " + successMessage);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The output in IE browser:

[image]

Edit:

The [deferred.then()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) method support IE browser. Perhaps you are using the deferred.then method.